# Create open directory replica of active directory server

Tags: active-directory, opendirectory

I have an active directory server running on windows server 2012, and a mac osx 10.6 server capable fo running open directory. Currently, my mac server is connected to my AD server, however I would like to set it up to be an open directory replica of it. However, every time I try to create one it asks me for the directory root password, and when I enter my windows server administrator password (since Windows doesen't have root) and it says it is incorrect. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make this work. Open Directory is too different to be able to replicate from an Active Directory domain. It can only replicate from Open Directory, and even there it's (mostly) restricted to the same major version of OS X Server (i.e. OS X Server v10.6 cannot replicate from anything other than v10.6).